# Warnings XST1293 and XST1896 during synthesis

Tags: vhdl

I am currently working on a game using VHDL as a programming language. I have been able to avoid laches from the start but on this one, I am completely lost...

I try to increment the level number when my small Mario reaches the end platform (to switch to the next level). So when he reaches this platform the signal `nextLevel_i` worth '1'.

I have implemented the code as follow:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use     IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity level is
    port (
            clk_i                   : in std_Logic;
            reset_i             : in std_Logic;
            nextLevel_i         : in std_Logic;
            elem01_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem02_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem03_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem04_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem05_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem06_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem07_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem08_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem09_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem10_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem11_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem12_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem13_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem14_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem15_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem16_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem17_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem18_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem19_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
            elem20_o                : out std_logic_vector (13 downto 0)
        );
end level;

architecture Behavioral of level is
    signal currentLevel_s       : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;
begin

processLevel : process (currentLevel_s)
begin
    elem01_o <= (others => '0');
    elem02_o <= (others => '0');
    elem03_o <= (others => '0');
    elem04_o <= (others => '0');
    elem05_o <= (others => '0');
    elem06_o <= (others => '0');
    elem07_o <= (others => '0');
    elem08_o <= (others => '0');
    elem09_o <= (others => '0');
    elem10_o <= (others => '0');
    elem11_o <= (others => '0');
    elem12_o <= (others => '0');
    elem13_o <= (others => '0');
    elem14_o <= (others => '0');
    elem15_o <= (others => '0');
    elem16_o <= (others => '0');
    elem17_o <= (others => '0');
    elem18_o <= (others => '0');
    elem19_o <= (others => '0');
    elem20_o <= (others => '0');
    case currentLevel_s is
        when 1 =>
            elem01_o <= "11111001010000";
            elem02_o <= "01110000110000";
            elem03_o <= "01110001010000";
            elem04_o <= "01110001110000";
            elem05_o <= "01110010010000";
            elem06_o <= "01110010110000";
            elem07_o <= "01110011010000";
            elem08_o <= "01110011110000";
            elem09_o <= "01110100010000";
            elem10_o <= "01110100110000";
            elem11_o <= "01110101010000";
            elem12_o <= "01110101110000";
            elem13_o <= "01110110010000";
            elem14_o <= "01110110110000";
            elem15_o <= "01110111010000";
            elem16_o <= "01110111110000";
            elem17_o <= "01111000010000";
            elem18_o <= "01111000110000";
            elem19_o <= "01110011101101";
            elem20_o <= "01110100001100";
        when 2 =>
    elem01_o <= "00010000010010";
        when others =>
            elem01_o <= "00100001010000";
            elem02_o <= "11111001010000";
    end case;
end process processLevel;

----------------------
-- nextLevel Logic
----------------------
processNextLevel : process (clk_i, reset_i)
begin
    if (reset_i = '1') then 
        currentLevel_s <= 0;
    elsif rising_edge(clk_i) then
        if (nextLevel_i = '1') then
            currentLevel_s <= currentLevel_s + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process processNextLevel;

end Behavioral;
```

Note: `currentLevel_s` is declared as follow:

```
signal currentLevel_s       : integer range 0 to 127 := 0;
```

I have then launched the synthesis and I get the following results:

[image: Synthesis result]

I think this result occurs because I do not affect a value to `currentLevel_s` (no `else` clause after the `if (reset_i = '1') then`). I simply want to keep the current value if the condition is not filled.

Any ideas how to solve these warnings ?

Comment: You are not showing sufficient code. The registers are optimized away. Probably because either `reset` is stuck at '1' or `nextLevel_i` is stuck at '0'... it could also be that the clock is not connected or fixed at '0'.

Comment: Thank you @J.H.Bonarius for the quick reply. from what I have tested, `reset_i` and `clock_i` are perfectly working.

Comment: good for you... But I'm still not able to reproduce your issue if you don't provide the code.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius, I Have added a more complete version of the code. I have checked the mapping too in my top level, they are good `clk_i`mapped to the output of my DCM clock. And `reset_i` is mapped to a switch of the FPGA. The full code is really big (and take nearly 20 minutes to achieve the synthesis) so it's really hard to add it here, if you need more code simply ask me witch parts you need and I will add them. Or I can send to you a full project archive if you prefer. Note: my code is working on the FPGA as I expect, I just want to suppress the warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy one:
You only do something when `currentLevel_s` is 1 ("01") or 2 ("10"). All other values don't matter. The synthesis tool optimizes away all other values.

Try adding `when 127 => [something]`.

Or just

```
signal currentLevel_s : integer range 0 to 3 := 0;

    if nextLevel_i = '1' and currentLevel_s < 3 then
        currentLevel_s <= currentLevel_s + 1;
    end if;
```

Comment: Thank you again for you reply. In my full code I go from `when 1 =>` to `when 8 =>` but you are totally true: the values 9 to 127 are unused now (but will be in the future for other levels). I will launch a new synthesis with a smaller range in a few minutes to see if it will remove these latches. Will keep you informed with the results ;)

Comment: @mq94 these are not latches... You misinterpret the warning: "FF/latch trimming" means "removing flip-flops _or_ latches". In this case its all flipflops.